# Loop through DIVS / Elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quick Explanation:

My code looks like that:

```
<div class="table">
 - div class 1 (in these divs 1-4 -> there a nested divs for Name / Score / ...)
 - div class 2
 - div class 3
 - div class 4
 - ...
</div>
```

I change the values with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('1').textContent=data.user[0].Score + "M";   
document.getElementById('1').textContent=data.user[1].Score + "M";   
document.getElementById('3).textContent=data.user[2].Score + "M";   
document.getElementById('3).textContent=data.user[3].Score + "M";
```

I know that I can FOR LOOP through this, but my problem is:

I want to loop through the children of my "table" class.
Therefore I don't have to write the numbers for "class=1" ... "class=2" 3 4 5 6

Comment: The code is kinda wrong and ugly. I just wanted to say, that i dont want to manually change my class names in the HTML section, but to somehow FOR LOOP through the nth-childs... in javascript.

Therefore i dont need to manually type 1-1000 after "class=..."

Comment: I dont see any loop like: `var children = tableFields.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var tableChild = children[i];
  // Do stuff
}`

Comment: If the children have classes assigned to them, you can loop through those rather than going through the parent.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
I would personally advise you switch up the JS to use the css query selector because it offers more flexibility and specificity. it also will return an array that you can iterate over with your for loop.

Comment: Yeah they have classes @ImmaNonner, but I dont want to write them all the time.
For each class I have to write like ... class=name1 ... class=name2 ...

If I have 1000 names its worthless. 
I just want to copy/paste the divs without changing the names and then nth-loop through it

Comment: @ImmaNonner you are technical incorrect. `querySelectorAll` does **not** return an array! It returns a **Node List** which is only an array like object. The difference is that you can't use array methods on a Node List and therefor need to convert the Node List to an array first.

Comment: "*My code looks like...*" could you *show* your relevant ("*[mcve]*") code, rather than...whatever that description/approximation was?

Comment: @tacoshy Thanks for the correction! Guess I need to refresh my memory on the NodeList methods there are.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all the child elements with a variable like:
`var children = document.querySelector('.container').children;`

Then you need a JS loop to loop through them which you can do with:
 `for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { /* commands */ }`

Then you need a counter that you can easily declare with a variable:
`var counter = 1;`

You rise that counter after each loop by declaring inside the loop:
`var counter = counter + 1;`

To add a class list with numebring you need to add a continios class-name through combing the class-name with the counter as variable:
`var className = "class-" + counter;`

Then you can add this class-name to every element by using:
`child.classList.add(className);`

```js
var children = document.querySelector('.container').children,
    counter = 1;
    
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {   
  var child = children[i];
  var className = "class-" + counter;
  
  /* just adds a counter to the innerHTML to demonstrate */
  child.innerHTML = "class = class-" + counter;
  
  /* what you actually want */
  child.classList.add(className);
  
  /* rises the counter */
  var counter = counter + 1;   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! That helped me / kinda solved it.

My goal was to be able to also route trough nested DIVS / ELEMENTS and change the text etc...
Additionally to your example with "class=container", for each child I have more nested divs. But I dont know how I can route through them too.
On an abstract basis its just nested "for - loops" but I dont know how to implement that here

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you correct you want to loop through the tables children and catch the contained divs by this right?
If so please try to select all divs which are children of the table by the help of [document.querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp). Done that you're able to loop through them like:

```js
const tableDivs = document.querySelectorAll("table div");

[...tableDivs].forEach((div, index) => {
  div.textContent = data?.user[index]?.Score + "M";
});
```

Since I only saw some pieces of code I'm not fully able to check the outcome. You might need to adapt some pieces to make it work but I'm sure you get the idea right?